error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-9): Error decoding the received TLS packet
(llm) root@gaojh-gpu-2-0:~/.vim/plugged/jedi-vim# git submodule update --init --recursive
Cloning into '/root/.vim/plugged/jedi-vim/pythonx/jedi'...
error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-9): Error decoding the received TLS packet.
error: 3093 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi.git' into submodule path '/root/.vim/plugged/jedi-vim/pythonx/jedi' failed
Failed to clone 'pythonx/jedi'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into '/root/.vim/plugged/jedi-vim/pythonx/jedi'...
error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-9): Error decoding the received TLS packet.
error: 5796 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi.git' into submodule path '/root/.vim/plugged/jedi-vim/pythonx/jedi' failed
Failed to clone 'pythonx/jedi' a second time, aborting

try for many times have setted git timeout、 buffer

This question is similar to: Github - unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
